# Extract the first long (11-14 digit) number from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to write a script (JS) to retrieve the first 11-14 digit long number from a URL string.

I am using the following RegEx expression:

```
\d{11}(?:\d?|\d{2,3})(?!\d)
```

But this retrieves all instances of 11-14 digit numbers ([example](http://regexr.com/3d20h)). How can I limit this so only the first instance is retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from other solutions which are successful in matching first instance of `11-14 digit` number this regex will accurately capture the `item` number.

**Regex:** `(?:item=?)?(\d{11,14})` Capture the first groups using `\1`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG0kW3/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

This will match a string of digits between 11 and 14 characters long

```
\d{11,14}
```

Comment: This with @ymranx's solution did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `g` from your existing solution.

[Demo here.](http://regexr.com/3d20k)

Comment: So simple. Thanks!